# Updating MySQL returns rows affected, but doesn't actually update the Database [ nodejs mysql2 ]

Tags: mysql, node.js, nodes, mysql2, node-mysql2

I have a function to run mysql2 nodejs with promise and update query

**Here is the output**:

```
{
        "fieldCount": 0,
        "affectedRows": 1,
        "insertId": 0,
        "info": "Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0",
        "serverStatus": 3,
        "warningStatus": 0,
        "changedRows": 1
}
```

but in the database the values don't change

this my lambda script

[script in gist github](https://gist.github.com/M1n007/48bf7cc914a31bdfd1d0765e23b834e9)

Comment: i am unfamiliar with nodejs and mysql, but have you set transaction mode? are you missing a commit maybe=

Comment: don't post code as  link  .. post text code  .. in your question

Comment: have you found a solution? I am in the same situation